# TFS Branch for Custom Version, Excluding those Customizations from Merging Back?

Tags: version-control, tfs, branching-and-merging

I recently inherited an ASP.Net Web Forms project that has no version control and I am trying to move it into TFS. At some point the project was split to make a custom version for a client where the login uses ADFS instead of our database-driven form. After the split some features were added to the main version to manage users; these were not needed in the custom version. Any changes to one version were manually applied to the other if they affected the non-customized parts (although, predictably, this was sometimes forgotten).

Each version had a folder on the dev and production servers, so the folder structure is like this:

```
/Production/General
/Production/Custom
/Dev/General
/Dev/Custom
```

Assuming it would be difficult to merge the two versions completely with feature toggles, what is the best approach to managing this?

I was thinking I could use diff to pull out what the production versions have in common and make that my MAIN branch. I could then make the two production versions branch from MAIN and have their current state as the first check-in, then do a similar thing for the dev folders, like this:

```
- MAIN
  | |- General
  |    |- GeneralDev
  |
  |- Custom
     |- CustomDev
```

However, I'm not sure how to manage merging. Is there a way to prevent certain files from merging only between certain branches? If I make a change in CustomDev I want to merge it normally to General, then I want to be able to get that change over to General and GeneralDev without pulling all the other customizations that Custom has...

Is there a way to do this well (without having to exclude files every time I merge), or do I just have to treat these as two separate projects and synchronize changes manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using branches should simplify the merging operation over just doing it manually, as the branches help you understand the history of changes. You may have to define a careful procedure for merging to ensure that merges are always done correctly - this may involve restricting the people who are allowed to merge, as often too many cooks can spoil the broth.

However, consider the ever increasing cost and risk of merging in this situation - it's a massive technical debt because any change that requires a merge costs you something like 4x as much to implement. Just testing that both branches are unaffected by a small change is difficult as you have to check in and merge before you can find out if it's ok - it's preferable to be able to build both variants on your PC and test them before you ever check anything in.

At the least you should work to minimise the merging needed, so look at where you can refactor the codebase (perhaps gradually over time) to reduce the need to merge. Look at the code where you get the most merge-churn. Perhaps you'll find that in your login class there are a couple of methods that need merging and the rest can be shared - so use a partial class or separate cpp files or break code up into helper or derived classes - anything that puts the implementations of these methods into separate files. Then you will only need to merge when a *shared* piece of code is touched, as opposed to continuously having to merge every change. Over time you may be able to properly isolate and modularise the non-shared code.

However, I'd recommend against branching in any situation where merges have to be bidirectional.

The other approach is the reverse of the branch-and=merge. Diff the two codebases, and wherever there is a difference, put both variants of the code together in a conditional compilation block (#if ... #else ... #endif) so that you can compile both variants from a single set of source code files. This is ugly, but allows you to work on the code without any branching or merging - your devs will still have to remember to compile both variants of the code to be sure that their changes work in both versions, but this is much easier than merging and rebuilding both variants. Again, over time, seek to modularise the differences so they can be minimised and/or conglomerated to minimise the impact. This approach also lends itself to perhaps allowing some parts of the behaviour to be changed to runtime rather than compile-time choices, so some behavious can be re-used in different  and more useful ways. With a decent diff tool (e.g. Araxis Merge) this shouldn't be too bad an option even with a large codebase. A few days of refactoring pain could save you years of trouble.

I know I'm suggesting what you're trying to avoid, but the sooner you take the pain of tackling the technical debt the better. Smoothing over the symptoms with branching will be easier in the short term, but will never fix the underlying problem... and the thing with technical debt is that the longer you leave it the worse it gets.